# How can I consistently set an environment variable for a single program?

Tags: environment-variables, thunderbird, defaults

I'm using `LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"` in general, and I'm happy with that. However, when I use Thunderbird, I'd like it to use a 12-hour clock. I've created a custom locale, and it works fine if I launch Thunderbird with

```
LC_TIME=en_AU_12h.utf8 /usr/bin/thunderbird
```

However, can I make Thunderbird launch like this by default? It seems to me that I'd have to make several modifications.

- I sometimes launch Thunderbird from my Desktop Environment, so I'd have to modify `thunderbird.desktop`.
- I sometimes launch Thunderbird from the command line, so I'd have to put the altered command in my `$PATH`, perhaps `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird`.
- I have a custom script to launch several programs at once, so that would also have to be modified.

Is there a way to change Thunderbird's default environment variables, so I don't have to change so many files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to create a script which calls the binary as part of the script. Then you can just set the variables in the script. In fact, it is not uncommon for executables corresponding to complex programs to be set up like that. E.g. `chromium`. So, if `/usr/bin/thunderbird` isn't already a script (check) you can create a script called `/usr/bin/thunderbird` or maybe `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird` and have it call the original `thunderbird` executable. Of course, you'd have to rename the original `thunderbird` for this to work

Comment: Ah, that's actually what I meant in the second point. However, I thought that `.desktop` files (and my custom script) wouldn't respect `/usr/local/bin/` in the `$PATH`, but I just checked and it works. So I actually already knew the answer, but your answer inspired me to check again! :) +1 and accepted.

Comment: Also, I didn't need to rename the original thunderbird, since I just put the custom script in `/usr/local/bin/`, which called `/usr/bin/thunderbird` (as per code in my question).

Comment: The system doesn't care whether the executable is in `/usr/local/bin`. However, if you are going to use both `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird` and `/usr/bin/thunderbird` in this fashion, you'll need to have `/usr/local/bin` first in your path.

Comment: Yep, it's first. For some reason I was confused and thought that this was defined in `~/.bashrc`. Hence, I wasn't sure if it'd get sourced everywhere. Of course, it's upstream of `~/.bashrc`, so that concern was irrelevant.

Comment: I think `/usr/local/bin`is already in PATH and `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in most distributions. It is in Debian.

Comment: Yes, it's the same in Arch Linux (in `/etc/profile`).

Comment: Yes, PATH is defined in `/etc/profile` on Debian too.